# Select distinct union with composite keys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, union, composite-primary-key

So, 
My current problem is creating a language file from php/pdo/mysql.  There are multiple language tables of identical structure but the application will only use 2 per run - a potentially incomplete user selected language and a complete fallback one.  For now we assume the english table is complete but any translation tables might not be, so we want any missing translations to be returned from the english one.

So, let's say the tables are lang_EN and lang_DE with columns section,type,label,content

lang_EN:

section:'admin', type:'button', label:'hello', content:'Hello World'

section:'admin', type:'button', label:'goodbye', content:'Goodbye Cruel World'

lang_DE:

section:'admin', type:'button', label:'hello', content:'Hallo Welt'

The primary key for the tables is a composite of (section,type,label).  There can be no other index - this is due to the way the language tables are populated and updated with an insert on duplicate key update query.

Due to server contraints constraints it has to be done in a single query.  I'm stuck in thinking the only way it can be done is via a union along the lines of

SELECT content FROM language_EN 
WHERE section = 'admin'
AND type = 'button'

UNION DISTINCT

SELECTcontent FROM language_DE
WHERE section = 'admin' 
AND type = 'button'

with expected results being:
Hallo Welt
Goodbye Cruel World

I know the query can be created easily by adding a matching index key in all tables, but due to the potential differences in language variations and the update manner that isn't possible, so I'm stumped right now.

Any pointers would be greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach:

```
(SELECT content
 FROM language_DE
 WHERE section = 'admin' AND type = 'button'
) UNION ALL
(SELECT content
 FROM language_EN en
 WHERE section = 'admin' and type = 'button' and
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM language_DE de
                   WHERE de.section = en.section and de.type = en.type and de.label = en.label
                  )
)
```

Two advantages over your approach.  First, you can choose additional columns and don't have to worry about `union distinct` missing duplicates.  Second, this uses the indexes and doesn't have an expensive duplicate removal operation.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I should sleep on this but couldn't.  I've adapted this approach and it only returns the results from the language_DE table.

Comment: @MrBob . . . That is saying that the second subquery is returning nothing.  Is that really true?

Comment: yes.  I could see where it was heading and you inspired me to get the answer below using row subqueries.

Comment: @MrBob . . . I missed that "label" is part of the key you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using row subquery constructors:

SELECT content FROM language_EN WHERE section = 'admin' AND type = 'button'

WHERE (section,type,label) NOT IN (SELECT section,type,label FROM language_DE)

UNION

SELECT content FROM language_DE WHERE section = 'admin' AND type = 'button'